# How would I extract the public and private keys from the apple world wide developer certificate and .p12 file?

Tags: java, ios, encryption, coldfusion

So I am attempting to write functionality for passbook or, as they call it now, "Wallet." I wrote all the necessary code to to write the JSON, write the files in a temp directory, then calculate the checksum and put in back in the manifest. Now I am stuck at the part where I sign the Apple World Wide Developer Certificate with the .p12 of the of the passes.P12 file to get the desired .der file?

```
<cfset signer = new rsa_signer(fileRead(expandPath("test_code/public_key.txt")),fileRead(expandPath("test_code/private_key.pem")),"SHA512withRSA")>


<cffile action="READ" file="#xtemp_folder#\manifest.json" variable="xtext">
<cfset xsignature = signer.sign(xtext)>
<!---- write to file ----->
<cffile action="WRITE" file="#xtemp_folder#\signature.der" output="#xsignature#">

<!---- create zipped file for user downloading ----->
<cf_write_log log_key="#attributes.log_key#" data="<hr>create zip files from temp holding folder..">
<cfset xzip_filename = "h:\eshowtemp\#xtemp_folder_string#.pkpass">
<cfdirectory action="LIST" directory="#xtemp_folder#" name="files">
<cf_write_log log_key="#attributes.log_key#" data="files=#files.recordcount#">
<cfzip file="#xzip_filename#" source="#xtemp_folder#">
```

The above code is a snippet of my cold fusion program that ideally signs and prints out the desired .pkpass file. I have confirmed this program works with other provided public and private keys. Where I read the signer, I have tried exporting the world wide developer certificate into a .pem file. I then did the same with the .p12, exporting that into a pem file and plugged both of the pem files into the rsa_signer and no luck. So I'm stuck where to go from here.

***Here's what I have noticed. On the public and private keys that do work, they look something like this:***

-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----

Encryption.....

-----END PRIVATE KEY-----

-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----

Encryption...
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----

***Compared to my 2 .pem files (Apple world wide developer cert + passes.p12 file)***

**///Apple dev cert.pem**

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

///Encryption

-----END CERTIFICATE-----

**//pass.pem (converted from .p12)**

Bag Attributes
    friendlyName: Pass Type ID: XXX
    localKeyID: XXX
subject=/UID=XXX/CN=Pass Type ID: XXX/OU=XXX/O=XXXC=US
issuer=/C=US/O=Apple Inc./OU=Apple Worldwide Developer Relations/CN=Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

XXXX
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

Could this be why my coldfusion program does not like my pem files? The .pem files say "Begin certificate" while the other pems say "Begin public/private key."

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

https://rietta.com/blog/2012/01/27/openssl-generating-rsa-key-from-command/

Comment: You seem to be confused. You will never see the private key of the Apple world wide developer certificate; Apple keeps this key **private**. The certificate you have has the public key which can be used to validate that something was signed by the possessor of the private key (I.e. Apple). You need to use *your* pass signing certificate which you get from the Apple developer site to sign your passes. Since you generate the CSR for this certificate you have the private key.

Comment: Once you get the signed certificate back from Apple you can load it into the KeyChain utility and then export it with the private key included

Answer (score 1):

step to create signature file is (after getting manifest.json)
1. load p12 file content (pass type id certification) -> $cert_info
2. decode $cert_info with password by using
openssl_pkcs12_read($cert_store, $cert_info, $password) -> $cert_info will keep all decoded info
3. get private key from $cert_info by using
$pkey = openssl_pkey_get_private($cert_info['pkey'], "");
and save $pkey into pem temp file
3.1 save cert info by using $cert = openssl_x509_read($cert_info['cert']);
4. use manifest.json, cert info ($cert), Apple World Wide Developer Certificate to make pkcs7 file (temp_signature) by using
openssl_pkcs7_sign("./pass_file/manifest.json", "./pass_file/temp_signature", $cert, $pkey, array(), PKCS7_BINARY | PKCS7_DETACHED, "./AppleWWDRCA.pem")
5. load temp_signature file content and extract data after filename="smime.p7s" and before ------ (substr) and encode with base64_decode and save into 'signature' file

Comment: @user3766198 hi im stuck also can you help me if it was worked for you. im not able to read certificate.p12  can you please share your solution please it will be great help